# javascript - get outerHTML with indentation

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to get outerHTML of element respecting oryginal indentation (or adding proper (new line and tab chars) basing on DOM tree?

so `mydiv.outerHTML` appended to `<pre>` element would look good (at the moment it would be like 1 long line of code - especially when element was created by js functions, not written with html)